# Computing data within nested dictionaries

Tags: python, python-3.x, loops, nested, nested-loops

I am working on a project which is a book recommendation algorithm which recommends books through multiplying the user input by the according user rating for that book and then sums all the user's ratings together.

```
biglist = [{'user1' : {'book1' : 0, 'book2' : -2, 'book3' : 3}}, 

            {'user2' : {'book1' : 0, 'book2' : 3, 'book3' : -3,}}, 

            {'user3' : {'book1' : 0, 'book2' : 5, 'book3' : 3}},

            {'user4': {'book1':2, 'book2':4, 'book3': 0}}]
```

Right now, I can print all the resulting multiplications but I am having troubles summing them for each user, this is what I have tried

```
    global new_ratings
    new_ratings=[]
    shuffle = random.sample(books,3)



def ratings():
    multi = []

    tmp = []
    isk = []

    global new_user_name
    new_user_name=input("enter your name ")
    new_names.append(new_user_name)
    global books_buff
    books_buff = books[:]
    for list_item in biglist: 

        for key, value in list_item.items(): 
            global key2
            global value2
            for key2, value2 in value.items():
                templist.append(value2)

    for i in range(3):

        x = shuffle[i]

        print(x)

        user_rating = int(input("")) 
        new_ratings.append(user_rating)
        for l in biglist:
            for key,value in l.items():
                for key2,value2 in value.items():

                    if user_rating != 0 and x == key2 :

                        multi = user_rating * value2
                        isk.append(multi)
                        fa = {}
                        fa[key2] = multi
                        print(multi)
                        tmp.append(fa)
    print(tmp)
    print(isk)
```

This is my desired output when the user inputs 2 such as:

```
book1:
2
book2:
2
book3:
2

[{'user1':{'book1':0,'book2':-4,'book3':6,'sum':2}},{'user2':{'book1':0,'book2':6,'book3':-6,'sum':0}},{'user3':{'book1':0,'book2':10,'book3':6,'sum':16}},{'user4':{'book1':4,'book2':8,'book3':0, 'sum':12}}]
```

Comment: Do you absolutely need to use global variables?

Comment: It was from a previous attempt when I was trying to use the variable in a different function

Comment: what do you mean of the variable of books?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure what your code is doing with all the global variables and the shuffling, but the task you describe (at least I think this is what you're describing, based on the desired output you gave) can mostly be accomplished with a few simple comprehension statements.

```
from typing import Dict, List


def scaled_ratings(
    biglist: List[Dict[str, Dict[str, int]]]
) -> List[Dict[str, Dict[str, int]]]:
    """
    Given a biglist of {user: {book: rating, book: rating}} dicts,
    prompt the user for a scaling factor to apply to the rating for each
    book, and return a new version of the list with all the ratings multiplied
    by the appropriate scaling factor, along with the sum of each user's ratings.
    """
    # First get the set of all books from biglist.
    all_books = sorted(list({
        b for d in biglist for r in d.values() for b in r.keys()
    }))

    # Now get the scaling factor for each book from the user.
    scale = {
        book: int(input(f"{book}:\n"))
        for book in all_books
    }

    # Now build a modified version of biglist with all the ratings scaled.
    scaled_ratings = [{user: {
        book: rating * scale[book]
        for book, rating in ratings.items()
    } for user, ratings in d.items()} for d in biglist]

    # Now add the sum into each ratings dict.
    for d in scaled_ratings:
        for ratings in d.values():
            ratings['sum'] = sum(ratings.values())
    return scaled_ratings


biglist = [
    {'user1': {'book1': 0, 'book2': -2, 'book3': 3}},
    {'user2': {'book1': 0, 'book2': 3, 'book3': -3}},
    {'user3': {'book1': 0, 'book2': 5, 'book3': 3}},
    {'user4': {'book1': 2, 'book2': 4, 'book3': 0}}
]
print(scaled_ratings(biglist))
```

Comment: Can you tell me if there are any bad practices in my approach?

Answer (score 1):

Here is what you can do:

```
r1 = int(input("Book1: "))
r2 = int(input("Book2: "))
r3 = int(input("Book3: "))
rs = [r1,r2,r3]

biglist = [ {'user1' : {'book1' : 0, 'book2' : -2, 'book3' : 3}}, 
            {'user2' : {'book1' : 0, 'book2' : 3, 'book3' : -3,}}, 
            {'user3' : {'book1' : 0, 'book2' : 5, 'book3' : 3}},
            {'user4' : {'book1' : 2, 'book2' : 4, 'book3' : 0}} ]

for d in biglist:
    s = 0
    for v in d.values():
        for k,r in zip(v.keys(),rs):
            v.update({k:v[k]*r})
            s += v[k]
    v.update({'sum':s})
print(biglist)
```

Input:

```
Book1: 2
Book2: 2
Book3: 2
```

Output:

```
[{'user1': {'book1': 0, 'book2': -4, 'book3': 6, 'sum': 2}}, {'user2': {'book1': 0, 'book2': 6, 'book3': -6, 'sum': 0}}, {'user3': {'book1': 0, 'book2': 10, 'book3': 6, 'sum': 16}}, {'user4': {'book1': 4, 'book2': 8, 'book3': 0, 'sum': 12}}]
```